# SSAS Date Filter Issue

Tags: ssas, tabular

In my SSAS Model, I add Year Filer(2020) and YearMonth Filter(2021 Jan) same Time.
Then my measure data disappeared.

[image: 1]

If I only add year filer then got the values.

Can't we add the year filters twice with different years

Comment: these are mutually exclusive, correct? You filter for all the dates that are at the same time 2020 and 2021 Jan, and 2021W01. You could filter Year to 2020 & 2021 but there only will be 2021 data showing because filters for YearMonth and Week exclude 2020

Comment: Got the point. Thanks a lot.....